# PHP - Elasticsearch: update multiple documents

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have a PHP array filled with ids. I would like to update all of my Elasticsearch documents according this array:

if the `id` of a document is

- in the array then set
  `my_fields` to `true`
- not in the array then set `my_field` to `false`

I use this elasticsearch-php package: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php.

Is there any "one query" solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `_update_by_query` along with `script` to set **my_field=true** like below. [See](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html), alternatively you can use `must_not` to set **my_field=false**

```
POST your_index_name/_update_by_query
{
  "query": {
      "bool": {
          "must": [
              {
                "terms": {"id": ["111","222","333"]}
              }
          ]
      }
  },
  "script" : "ctx._source.my_field = true;"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there any way to set true and false in one go?

Comment: You can see here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-examples.html for some examples of painless, not sure this work for sure or not but I guess it will help you :)